# Can I connect an audio node to 2 different nodes?

Tags: web-audio-api

I'm working with the web audio API. Say I have a source buffer node. Is there any way that I could connect it to 2 different delay nodes? Like

```
var sourceNode = context.createBufferSource();
sourceNode.buffer = myBuffer;
sourceNode.connect(delayNode1);
sourceNode.connect(delayNode2);
```

? The way I have it here does not work. It only connects to `delayNode2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course.  I'm not sure why you're not finding that code to work; it absolutely should (and similar code works for me).  If you have it running in place somewhere I can take a look.